# Image problems with magento - broken images are displayed after uploading an image

Tags: php, magento

I'm uploading products to my Magento store but products are not being displayed, I can upload the image using the admin area, and when managing my products I can't see the images there it seems my picture is broken, then I go to the front end it still not appear, any idea guys?

[image]

Actually it's crash all of the category pics and product pic:

[image: actually it's crash all of the catagory pics and product pic]

Answer (score 0):

First check the media folder (using ftp if it's running on a server) and search for the images. If they are present, then it is a displaying problem, it could be that the image's url's are wrong or the path is protected. Using the browser console can verify that.

If the images are not present, there is a problem with uploading. Make sure the media folder is writeable, that you have a correct version of flash installed (maybe try another browser) and check the Magento log files (var/system/log/) for any errors.

If any of this got you any further, please let us know.